# Prevent Others from deleting a user

Tags: user-management

When I as a main user add a user with adduser command and give the added user sudo access.

But afterwards I can delete this user without entering the password associated with this user. I want to just the added user itself can delete it and no one else can apply any change to this user.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: An user can't dlete itself, only other user with sudo privileges can.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want others have the permission to delete this user. Is there any way?

Comment: Any user with sudo privileges can, by definition. Having multiple root users isn't a good practice, all the opposite.

Comment: Can Sudo users access to home and files of other users too?

Comment: But when sudo user can delete other users (sudo or non-sudo ones), it isn't safe. I can't understand how to manage this issue?

Comment: Don't distribute `sudo` like a blanket. It's Not Safe. Read `man sudo sudoers`. You can grant access to certain commands as `root` or other users. Any `root` user can remove the user from `/etc/passwd`, read/delete unencrypted `HOME` directories (and encrypted `HOME` dirs while the user is logged in), kill all the user's processes, ...

Comment: @Marz Not only can a sudo user delete another user, they can delete the whole system.

Comment: To make it even more abundantly clear, and not just about users and passwords, anyone with sudo access can do anything they want to the system. This is by design. The sudo command means the user owns the system, without any limitations.